# Discord bot (JS) messageReactionAdd not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am building a Discord bot using JS. Now I want to add reaction roles.

The event `messageReactionAdd` does not work for me. This is my code:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
  ]
})

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log('Message react');
});
```

It looks very simple but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to react to older messages or to messages sent after the bot became ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted does work on cached messages. The intents are correct, however, if you don't enable partial structures, your code only works on messages posted after the bot is connected.

Reacting on older messages won't fire the `messageReactionAdd` event. If you also want to listen to reactions on old messages you need to enable partial structures for `Message`, `Channel` and `Reaction` when instantiating your client, like this:

```js
const {
  Client,
  EmbedBuilder,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  Partials,
} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.Reaction,
  ],
});
```